# Newman CLI treating strings in CSV differently from POSTMAN - parsing failure

Tags: csv, postman, newman, postman-collection-runner

Newman Version (can be found via newman -v): 4.2.2

OS details (type, version, and architecture): Windows 10 Pro Version 1803 Running all files locally, but hitting internal API

Are you using Newman as a library, or via the CLI? CLI

Did you encounter this recently, or has this bug always been there: This is a new collection

Expected behaviour: I need to use a CSV file to import data into the response body of POST requests. All values MUST be strings. My CSV works correctly in POSTMAN, but fails with **error: Invalid closing quote at line 2; found """ instead of delimiter ","** in NEWMAN.

Command / script used to run Newman: newman run allPatients.postman_collection.json -e New_QA.postman_environment.json -d 2.csv

Sample collection, and auxiliary files (minus the sensitive details):
In POSTMAN, when I run the requests, all values are strings and must be surrounded by doubled quotes. I use a CSV file that looks like this:

**"bin","pcn","group_id","member_id","last_name","first_name","dob","sex","pharmacy_npi","prescriber_npi"
"""012353""","""01920000""","""TESTD 273444""","""Z9699879901""","""Covg""","""MC""","""19500101""","""2""","""1427091255""","""1134165194"""**

*When I run the same CSV data file in NEWMAN, I get the error above.* I have tried a few options I've seen on this forum without any luck such as using Escape syntax for double quotes such as:
"/"text/""

The only things I've tried that have not failed pre-run with an error like above include removing the double-quotes entirely or replacing them with single-quotes. When I do this, I get 400 Bad Request, which I suspect is due to me sending invalid data-types.

Answer (score 0):

Please close this issue. It was the result of human error.

I was able to fix this by correctly using the syntax suggested elsewhere.

**"bin","pcn","group_id","member_id","last_name","first_name","dob","sex","pharmacy_npi","prescriber_npi"
"\"012353\"","\"01920000\"","\"TESTD  273444\"","\"Z9699879901\"","\"Covg\"","\"MC\"","\"19500101\"","\"2\"","
\"1427091255\"","\"1134165194\""**